# how add custom tag/tool in classic editor?

Tags: html, editor

at this moment i dont use new wp block editor still using classic html editor and at this moment were editing lots of articles in foreign language..default WordPress editor is something like this

[image: wp editor]

if use italic tag on foreign word `Encephalartos horridus` it become like this `<em>Encephalartos horridus</em>`
while what im trying to achieve is like this `<i lang="la">Encephalartos horridus</i>`

and since most the length article im currently working are to long (8k words),manually editing them one by one is just to tedious

is there any plugins or maybe a way to add custom tag in WordPress editor so i could just click them

Comment: You can switch back to the old WYSIWYG editor, by specifying `'show_in_rest' => false`.